# Windows 7 AntivirusOverride Key Access Denied

Tags: windows-registry

I am trying to make a setup application that changes to key Software/Microsoft/Security Center/svc/AntiVirusOverrides to 1, however it gives me an error 'Access Denied' even when I run it as administrator. Furthermore, I tried using regedit with the same privileges, however it gave a similar error message.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first Take Ownership of the `Svc` key, then give the \Users (or whomever you wish) Full Control permissions.

Once that's done you can change that entry.

After you've made the change to that value data, I'd advise setting the ownership and permissions back to how they were before you changed them.